# How to fix/remove isc-dhcp-server

Tags: server

For a long time I've had problems about the setup of my `dhcp-server`. I had the thought of reinstalling the OS and fix the problem that way but that isn't the correct way of solving the issue in this world.

So now I'm aiming for a solution from you guys :-)

When ever I do an `apt-get upgrade` or try to remove the `isc-dhcp-server`

I get the same errors:

```
the followig packeges have unmet dependencies.
isc-dhcp-server: depends: isc-dhcp-common (= 4.2.4-7ubuntu12) but 4.2.4-7ubuntu12.1 is installed
```

or

```
invoke-rc.d: dangling symlink: /etc/rc2.d/S20isc-dhcp-server6
dpkg: error processing package isc-dhcp-server (--purge):
subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 102
errors were encountered while processing:
isc-dhcp-server
E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

To solve it I've tried a whole lot. `sudo apt-get -f install` returns the same errors. If I try to solve it through `Synaptic` or `Aptitude` the result is the same. If I try to install `Webmin` to attempt a fix through this interface the result is the same.

What am I to do? I'm completely lost right now...?